# How to set a property on a set of controls

Tags: c#, .net

So, I am doing this, wanting to be cool:

```
List<CheckButton> cbuttons = new List<CheckButton>(
    new CheckButton[] { 
        cbShowAll, 
        cbShowApproved, 
        cbShowNew, 
        cbShowQC, 
        cbShowSent });
cbuttons.ForEach(b => b.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false);
```

Is there a more cool way to do it?

EDIT:

There might be `CheckButton`s that won't be affected.  There might be multiple property and/or method calls per group.

Comment: Are these buttons grouped in an element otherwise?

Comment: By what rule you are grouping buttons into array? Is there any other buttons on your parent control?

Comment: What you mean by `cool`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan votes will tell :)

Answer (score 3):

To make it applicable for many such controls like `TextBox` or `CheckBox`, create an extension method on the Form like so:

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    public static void ChangeAll<T>(this Form form, string propName, object value) where T : Control
    {
        foreach (Control c in form.Controls.OfType<T>())
        {
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propName);
            if (myPropInfo != null)
            {
                myPropInfo.SetValue(c, value, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and we can call it:

```
this.ChangeAll<CheckBox>("Checked", false);
this.ChangeAll<Button>("Text", "DefaultButtonName");
this.ChangeAll<TextBox>("Text", "DefaultText");
```

where `this` is `Form1 : Form`

Answer (score 2):

Unless that list is dynamic, doing it the “boring” way will be likely more efficient:

```
cbShowAll.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
cbShowApproved.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
cbShowNew.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
cbShowQC.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
cbShowSent.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
```

Other than that, you could subclass the `CheckButton` and make that the default value too.

Also, in general “readable and possibly efficient” is much better than “cool and fancy”.

Comment: I forgot that I have actually more than one property or method to set, but I won't change it now since it is the question as it is...

Comment: Well, if it’s more than a single operation, you could make a `InitializeCheckBox` method that takes a check box as the parameter and does all that stuff. And then simply call that method for each check box. If it’s a static set of check boxes, then you still won’t use that list/foreach way.

Answer (score 2):

If you're performing some one-off initialization on a particular subset of controls (rather than all of them), then you could create an array containing that subset and then enumerate the array:

```
foreach (CheckButton button in
    new[] { cbShowAll, cbShowApproved, cbShowNew, cbShowQC, cbShowSent })
{
    button.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
}
```

Using a loop allows you to avoid duplicate code (as in poke's answer).

**Note:** Eric Lippert wrote a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) explaining why he prefers `foreach` over `ForEach`. Excerpt:

> [Providing a ForEach extension method] lets you rewrite this perfectly clear code:
>
> ```
> foreach (Foo foo in foos) { statement involving foo; }
> ```
>
> into this code:
>
> ```
> foos.ForEach((Foo foo) => { statement involving foo; });
> ```
>
> which uses almost exactly the same characters in slightly different order. And yet the second version is harder to understand, harder to debug, and introduces closure semantics, thereby potentially changing object lifetimes in subtle ways.

Also, not all versions of the .NET Framework support `List<T>.ForEach`. For example, if you're writing a Windows Store app, you need to use `foreach` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that with all the CheckBoxes you have inside of a form or control, you don't need to hard code the array. If you're hard coding everything, then I agree with poke's answer.

However, you could be totally dynamic and if this is something you want to be reusing in many places, you could have a utility method (or something in a base form or control class that fires after the `InitializeComponents()` method).

If you want that, you could do something like this:

```
this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
             .ForEach(b => b.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false);
```

If you don't want to do that with **every** CheckBox, you could create a subclass of those, and substitute that class name in the `OfType` generic declaration.